# Providing Standard Library for embedded Python

Tags: python, mobile, embed, standard-library

I've successfully embedded Python in a multi-platform C++ project.

This required linking to a libpython, which needs to be provided for each platform I'm targeting.  For OSX it was easy, I just pulled it out of some homebrew folder.

But I would like my Python scripts to use imports from the standard library (e.g. [this one](https://gist.github.com/p-i-/6dd9f79560895265ba49#file-gistfile1-py-L76))

What is that going to involve?

[Standard Library documentation for Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) says that the standard library is a mix of compiled units and .py files, so I'm expecting I will have to maybe link my project against a second library, and somehow inform the Python runtime of the location of the folder containing the standard library's .py files.

But is it really going to be this simple? Is this process documented anywhere?

Am I going to run into trouble on mobile platforms? It looks as though [Kivy](http://kivy.org/docs/faq.html#does-kivy-support-python-3-x) might be on their way towards solving this problem...

Comment: Most projects that embed Python do so statically and include all extension modules that they need in the binary (so again linked statically). The Python files from the stdlib are then included as a zip file. If you have Sublime Text 3 installed, take a look at their `Contents/MacOS/` folder, you'll see a `python3.3.zip` file.

Comment: @Clifford, why remove the `embed` tag? It is no less relevant than the other tags... In fact it is more relevant than the `mobile` tag!

Comment: @Pi : I didn't; I removed "embedded" which has a different meaning. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded/info